# TwiML script skips over Record verb and won't record a message

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I've gone through this seemingly simple TwiML (Twilio) issue over and over but can't figure out what's going on.

**My Objective**: Place an inbound call in Queue while an outbound call is made to an agent to see if they can take the call. If the agent can take the call, then the two calls are bridged. If an agent can't take the call, then the caller hears hold music for about a minute, which is followed by a message asking them to leave a voicemail. After the caller leaves a voicemail, the call should hang up.

**What Happens**: Upon accepting an inbound call, the caller hears a brief message and is then Enqueued (this works). An outbound call is made to an agent (this works), and if they can take the call, they do (this works). If the agent can't take the call, then the caller hears hold music for about a minute and then a message asking them to leave a voicemail (this works). Then, instead of giving the caller an opportunity to leave a voicemail, the call abruptly hangs up. The Record verb is seemingly skipped over as though it's not there, and the flow goes directly to Hangup.

Here's the code for taking the incoming call and the Enqueue waitUrl:

**incoming-call.php**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Say voice="Polly.Joanna-Neural">Please wait while I find someone to speak with you.</Say>
  <Enqueue waitUrl="wait-url.php">support</Enqueue>
</Response>
```

**wait-url.php**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Play loop="1">../../audio-files/hold-music/smile.mp3</Play>
  <Say voice="Polly.Joanna-Neural">I'm sorry, but I couldn't reach anyone to take your call. Please leave a message, and someone will return your call as soon as possible. Have a great day!</Say>
  <Record timeout="10" />
  <Hangup/>
</Response>
```

I've tried reconfiguring the Record verb with and without a recordingStatusCallback url, with and without a timeout, and even with nothing at all. In every instance the call just ends without recording a message.

Thank you in advance for any thoughts or suggestions on how to solve this.

Comment: I've since realized Record is not an accepted verb to be used in a waitUrl. I reconfigured the wait-url.php script by replacing Record & Hangup with Redirect, which is an accepted verb for a waitUrl. The Redirect sends the call flow to a file that includes a Record verb followed by Hangup. Unfortunately, the same thing happens. The call just hangs up without giving the caller an opportunity to leave a message. I'm still perplexed as to what might be going on. Even though the flow was redirected to another url, is it still considered part of the waitUrl, and hence, unable to process Record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue, as you have described in your comment, is that your call remains in the queue and the TwiML you are dealing with can only be `waitUrl` friendly TwiML.

What you need is for the call to leave the queue, then it can continue with all available TwiML. You can have a call leave the queue with the [`<Leave>` TwiML element](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/leave). When a call leaves the queue it continues with the next TwiML after the `<Enqueue>` element. I assume, based on your current implementation, that your mp3 file is about the length you want the caller to stay in the queue.

So in your case you can update your TwiML to the following:

**incoming-call.php** - enqueues the call, but also handles recording voicemail once the caller leaves the queue.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Say voice="Polly.Joanna-Neural">Please wait while I find someone to speak with you.</Say>
  <Enqueue waitUrl="wait-url.php">support</Enqueue>

  <Say voice="Polly.Joanna-Neural">I'm sorry, but I couldn't reach anyone to take your call. Please leave a message, and someone will return your call as soon as possible. Have a great day!</Say>
  <Record timeout="10" />
  <Hangup />
</Response>
```

**wait-url.php** - plays the mp3, then leaves the queue.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Play loop="1">../../audio-files/hold-music/smile.mp3</Play>
  <Leave />
</Response>
```

Comment: Thank you Phil. Yes, I figured that out finally. The Leave verb was the answer. Thank you for the detailed response. I've learned a lot from reading your other posts here on SO.

Comment: Hey Jason, glad you got that sorted. Since this was the answer too, do you mind marking it as correct? So glad to hear that my other answers have helped too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the Enqueued calls CallSid to point to a new TwiML source (which includes the Record verb). You will trigger this if the agent can’t take the call.